# visual basic Sql query runs on developement pc, not other

Tags: sql, vb6

I am facing a strange issue, I have an old large **VB6** app with **datareports**. It's large, so please don't suggest migrating etc.

I have a datareport on it which filters by date. the report works well on development PC but shows

```
"no value given for one or more required parameters"
```

or

```
"item cannot be found in this ordinal"
```

on all other PC's. This is quite strange as i have all the files.

Any known similar problem..

Comment: I'm not going to suggest migrating, but I am going to suggest you show the code that generates the report.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having a similar issue, i found a solution..so this may help in future.. the issue is purely bcoz the database is in the program files folder on non development machine and so full rights are not available to the app.. Try changing the db location outside program files and it'll all be perfect..